# Spring Data Cassandra - Making a Column Static

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I am looking into the Spring Data provider for Cassandra and don't see a way to specify a column as static when a table includes clustering keys. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

There's no CQL generation support for `static` columns. Do you want to file an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS?

For now, create the CQL of this table yourself.

Comment: OK, that was kind of what i was expecting, thanks for confirming! Since i am just getting to know Cassandra I'll go ahead with creating the CQL myself and submit an issue if needed. Thanks again!